# Running a server on eclipse tomcat, i need to find MAC address of all the connected clients

Tags: eclipse, macos, networking, server

I want to set up a security filter and want to get MAC address of all the client in my server i used the following code in my eclipse local server and i am not able to get clients MAc address rather end up getting my server MAC address every time.

Screen Shot of my code.
[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: If the client is not on the local network it can't be done, see [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/25604/30382)

Comment: Using MAC addresses for security is a fool's game because it is so easy to change a MAC address, which is only seen or relevant on the LAN to which the host is connected.